# How to read and parse html from files or from string?

Tags: rust, html-parser, yew

- **goal** convert this HTMl string into macro or into node element

```rust
use html_parser::Dom;

let html = r#"<span class="text_editor"><h1 title="title is here">hello world</h1><p>hi paragraph</p></span>"#;
let nodes = Dom::parse(html).unwrap_throw();

// add the html
let doc = window().unwrap_throw().document().unwrap_throw();
let my_dom_element = &doc.get_element_by_id("1").unwrap_throw();
my_dom_element.append_child(&nodes.children[0]).unwrap_throw();
```

```js
31 |         my_dom_element.append_child(&nodes.children[0]).unwrap_throw();
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `web_sys::Node`, found enum `html_parser::Node`
```

Comment: Do you want to populate the document with the content of your string "html" ?
If so, I think that you should try using : this method set_inner_html of the root element of the document : https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.HtmlElement.html#method.set_inner_html .

I don't think that html_parser can interact with web_sys. (because you are doing a WASM library isn't it ?)

Comment: Wow man it worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

```rust
use web_sys::{window};

let doc = window().unwrap_throw().document().unwrap_throw();
let my_dom_element = &doc.get_element_by_id("1").unwrap_throw();
let html = r#"<span class="text_editor"><h1 title="title is here">hello world</h1><p>hi paragraph</p></span>"#;
my_dom_element.set_inner_html(html);
```